# Chrome inspect element -> Preview shows different than clicking XHR link

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

This is what I see under preview:

```
{C: "d-64E78C04-B,0|Wm,1|Wn,2",…}
    C: "d-64E78C04-B,0|Wm,1|Wn,2"
    M: [{H: "InsuranceOfferRequestHub", M: "ReceiveCaptcha", A: [{id: 6057043, valid: true}]}]
```

This is what I see when I click the link, which looks something like this: 
https://forsikringsguiden.dk/signalr/poll?transport=longPolling&clientProtocol=2.1&connectionToken=%2BfuC59NdzGOF9AM7vTrn%2FGdFVp1ichfhw3mXduUlCtyTWG1ZaAUfvp5H2KM8JC9Uns8MhINiAfIO0NLxsVpwLjH8Pz3uWcNN9TZMuwBr0mzNqG9JuRmris4TabhPOUHp&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22insuranceofferrequesthub%22%7D%5D
The link is probably timed out, as it changes.

I get the output below from by clicking the link above I see under Chrome -> Inspect Element -> Preview -> XHR:

```
{'C': 'd-64E78C04-B,0|Wk,11|Wl,2', 'M': []}
```

Here's the full code below.

I use a combination of Selenium and Requests. By using Selenium I fill out several forms and end, at the final page which is https://forsikringsguiden.dk/resultat. This is an overview of prices for different firms and insurance.

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


class Main:
    BASE_URL = 'https://forsikringsguiden.dk'
    browser = None
    fname = ''
    workbook = None
    worksheet = None
    row = 1
    #headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}


    def __init__(self):
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        chrome_options.add_argument(
            'user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36"')
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
        self.browser.get(self.BASE_URL)

        self.fname = "F:\*\*\Data_Mining\Forsikringsguiden\XHR_URLS.xlsx"
        self.workbook = Workbook()
        self.worksheet = self.workbook.worksheets[0]
        self.write_headers()

    def write_headers(self):
        self.worksheet.cell(row=self.row, column=1).value = 'indbo'
        self.row = self.row + 1

    def write(self, col, val):
        self.worksheet.cell(row=self.row, column=col).value = val
        self.row = self.row + 1
        self.workbook.save(self.fname)

    def fill_fields(self):
        x=6 # for time.sleep()
        self.browser.maximize_window()
        time.sleep(x)
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[3]/app-footer/app-cookie/section/div/div/div/div[2]/div/button').click()
        time.sleep(3)
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[2]/app-start/section[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]').click()
        time.sleep(6)
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[2]/app-start/section[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[7]/div/div[2]/div/a[2]').click()
        time.sleep(5)
        self.browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,900)", "")
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="vogntype"]/div/div/input').click()
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="vogntype"]/div/div/input').send_keys(
            "Kongshaven 86, 2500 Valby")
        #time.sleep(x)
        time.sleep(3)
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rankingAge"]').click()
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rankingAge"]').send_keys("40")
        #self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/form/div/div[2]/button/i').click()
        #input("Enter q To continue")
        time.sleep(x)
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[2]/app-common/section/div/div/fieldset/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/select').click()
        time.sleep(x)
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[2]/app-common/section/div/div/fieldset/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/select').send_keys("2", Keys.TAB)
        time.sleep(x)
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[2]/app-common/section/div/div/fieldset/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/select').send_keys("2", Keys.TAB)
        time.sleep(x)
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[2]/app-common/section/div/div/fieldset/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/button').click()
        self.browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,900)", "")
        time.sleep(x)
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/app-root/app-product-layout/div/div[2]/app-furnishing/section/div/div/app-product-navigate/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/button').click()
        time.sleep(x)
        #self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('///*[@id="wrapper"]/div[2]/app-furnishing/section/div/div/app-product-navigate/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/button').click()
        #input('Enter x When you done')
        # self.browser.refresh()
        time.sleep(15)
        #self.requests.get()
        #soup = BeautifulSoup(self.browser.requests, 'lxml').text
        #company_id = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"company-image"}) 
        #print(soup)

        count = 1
        for request in self.browser.requests:
            if request.response:
                if 'poll?transport' in request.path:
                    print(count, request.path)
                    count = count + 1
                    self.write(1, request.path)

        #self.browser.quit()            
bj = Main()
bj.fill_fields()
#%%
import pandas as pd

site = pd.read_excel("F:\*\*\Data_Mining\Forsikringsguiden\XHR_URLS.xlsx", header = 0)
xhr = site.iloc[0]["indbo"]
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36',
          'Referer':'https://forsikringsguiden.dk/resultat'
          }

request_data = requests.get(url = xhr, headers = header)
req_json = request_data.json()
request_data.close()
request_data.connection.close()

print(req_json)
```

Am I missing more headers?